# Why do boxed closures in structs require 'static lifetime?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I am playing with Rust in some side projects, and while loving the ecosystem, safety and predictability of everything I write I am hitting some bumps along the road. Currently the name of the bump is storing closures into `Box<T>` withing struct. Here is what I have up to now.

The following example produces an error which seems to have to do something with the fact that `Fn` trait is implemented on `&T` for all types `T: ?Sized + Fn`. Here is what I am getting:

```rust
pub struct AdditiveNoiseExtendedKalmanFilter<Num>
where
    Num: Scalar + Lapack,
{
    transition_function: Box<dyn Fn(&ArrayView2<Num>) -> Array2<Num>>,
    transition_function_jacobian: Box<dyn Fn(&ArrayView2<Num>) -> Array3<Num>>,
    measurement_function: Box<dyn Fn(&ArrayView2<Num>) -> Array2<Num>>,
    measurement_function_jacobi: Box<dyn Fn(&ArrayView2<Num>) -> Array3<Num>>,
    transition_covariance: Array2<Num>,
    measurement_covariance: Array2<Num>,
}

impl<Num> AdditiveNoiseExtendedKalmanFilter<Num> where
    Num: Scalar + Lapack
{
    pub fn new(
        transition_function: impl Fn(&ArrayView2<Num>) -> Array2<Num>,
        transition_function_jacobi: impl Fn(&ArrayView2<Num>) -> Array3<Num>,
        measurement_function: impl Fn(&ArrayView2<Num>) -> Array2<Num>,
        measurement_function_jacobi: impl Fn(&ArrayView2<Num>) -> Array3<Num>,
        transition_covariance: &ArrayBase<impl Data<Elem = Num>, Ix2>,
        measurement_covariance: &ArrayBase<impl Data<Elem = Num>, Ix2>,
    ) -> Self
    {
        AdditiveNoiseExtendedKalmanFilter {
            transition_function: Box::new(transition_function),
            transition_function_jacobian: Box::new(transition_function_jacobi),
            measurement_function: Box::new(measurement_function),
            measurement_function_jacobi: Box::new(measurement_function_jacobi),
            transition_covariance: transition_covariance.to_owned(),
            measurement_covariance: measurement_covariance.to_owned()
        }
    }
}
```

```
error[E0310]: the parameter type `FUN1` may not live long enough
   --> src/filter/extended_kalman.rs:108:26
    |
93  |     pub fn new<FUN1, FUN2, JAC1, JAC2>(
    |                ---- help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound...: `FUN1: 'static`
...
108 |     transition_function: Box::new(transition_function),
    |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ...so that the type `FUN1` will meet its required lifetime bounds


error[E0310]: the parameter type `JAC1` may not live long enough
   --> src/filter/extended_kalman.rs:109:35
    |
93  |     pub fn new<FUN1, FUN2, JAC1, JAC2>(
    |                            ---- help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound...: `JAC1: 'static`
...
109 |     transition_function_jacobian: Box::new(transition_function_jacobi),
    |                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ...so that the type `JAC1` will meet its required lifetime bounds


error[E0310]: the parameter type `FUN2` may not live long enough
   --> src/filter/extended_kalman.rs:110:27
    |
93  |     pub fn new<FUN1, FUN2, JAC1, JAC2>(
    |                      ---- help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound...: `FUN2: 'static`
...
110 |     measurement_function: Box::new(measurement_function),
    |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ...so that the type `FUN2` will meet its required lifetime bounds


error[E0310]: the parameter type `JAC2` may not live long enough
   --> src/filter/extended_kalman.rs:111:34
    |
93  |     pub fn new<FUN1, FUN2, JAC1, JAC2>(
    |                                  ---- help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound...: `JAC2: 'static`
...
111 |     measurement_function_jacobi: Box::new(measurement_function_jacobi),
    |                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ...so that the type `JAC2` will meet its required lifetime bounds
```

As I was writing the code above I thought that I am transferring the ownership of closure into the function `AdditiveNoiseExtendedKalmanFilter<Num>::new`, and then into `Box`, and thus did not expect lifetimes to play any role at all.

Now when I change the definition of the function to following it works just fine, but I do not want the users of my function to have to wrap their closures into boxes:

```rust
//THIS ONE WORKS:
impl<Num> AdditiveNoiseExtendedKalmanFilter<Num> where
    Num: Scalar + Lapack
{
    pub fn new(
        transition_function: Box<dyn Fn(&ArrayView2<Num>) -> Array2<Num>>,
        transition_function_jacobi: Box<dyn Fn(&ArrayView2<Num>) -> Array3<Num>>,
        measurement_function: Box<dyn Fn(&ArrayView2<Num>) -> Array2<Num>>,
        measurement_function_jacobi: Box<dyn Fn(&ArrayView2<Num>) -> Array3<Num>>,
        transition_covariance: &ArrayBase<impl Data<Elem = Num>, Ix2>,
        measurement_covariance: &ArrayBase<impl Data<Elem = Num>, Ix2>,
    ) -> Self
    {
        AdditiveNoiseExtendedKalmanFilter {
            transition_function: transition_function,
            transition_function_jacobian: transition_function_jacobi,
            measurement_function: Box::new(measurement_function),
            measurement_function_jacobi: Box::new(measurement_function_jacobi),
            transition_covariance: transition_covariance.to_owned(),
            measurement_covariance: measurement_covariance.to_owned()
        }
    }
}
```

It seems to me that adding a requirement, that passed in closures have 'static lifetime overly restrictive, since this is a library. Am I wrong ?

Comment: The parameter of `Box::new` should have the same type as the contents. When provided references as arguments, you are effectively coercing a reference to closure to `dyn Fn` objects, so storing them in `Box`es does not prolong the lifetime of the actual function objects. (In that case, you are effectively storing `Box<&Fn(...)>`.)

Comment: Yes, but the `new` function does not take references to structs which implement the trait.

Comment: I might have not expressed myself clearly. The rust compiler cannot guarantee that `FUN1` is *not a reference*. So in case it is a reference, it must live long enough. Since `Box`es are values, which might live forever, to prevent dangling references, the only possible lifetime is `'static`. In the case that `FUN1` is not a reference type, adding `'static` would not restrict the function (moving objects does not preserve the “top-level” lifetime bound.)

Comment: The point is, your function itself might accept a reference to closure, and *that* lifetime should be guaranteed long enough.

Comment: Can I write the function, so that only owned types are allowed and no references?

Comment: That would be the `'static` requirement verbatim. What you might want to do is redefine the parameters to be `impl (Fn(input) -> Ouput + 'static)` to make the input closures not be references (nor be allowed to contain references. Otherwise, you would have to add a lifetime parameter to your struct, and apply it to the contents of the boxes.